How to check if a GitHub action is running in a public repo or a private repo?
We can get various variables in GitHub Actions like github.event.repository.default_branch for getting the default branch.
Is there any field in github object that can be used to determine if the repo is private or public?

github.event.repository is the payload described in the API docs to retrieve one repo. There are two fields you could use:

There's a boolean private field, so github.event.repository.private
There's a string-valued visibility field, so github.event.repository.visibility (one of private, public, or internal)

